# В mysqli не работает utf8

Tags: php, mysqli

Добрый день. В БД записываются кракозябры.
Пробовал вставить `mysqli_set_charset("utf8")` - не помогло. Как исправить эту проблему с этим кодом?

```
class dbMySQLi{
public $count_sql = 0;
public $query = false;
public $mysqli = false;
public $error_connect = false;
public $error_query = false;
public $insert_id = false;

public function connect(){
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        $this->error_connect = true;
        die(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}

public function query($query){
    if(!$this->mysqli) $this->connect();
    if(!$this->query = $this->mysqli->query($query)){
        $this->error_query = true;
        die(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $this->count_sql++;
    $this->insert_id = $this->mysqli->insert_id;

    return $this->query;
}

public function get_row($query){
    if(!$this->mysqli) $this->connect();
    return $query->fetch_assoc();
}

public function get_num_rows($query){
    if(!$this->mysqli) $this->connect();
    return $query->num_rows;
}

public function safe_sql($sql){
    if(!$this->mysqli) $this->connect();
    return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($sql);
}

public function version(){
    if(!$this->mysqli) $this->connect();
    return $this->mysqli->server_info;
}

public function close(){
    if($this->mysqli) $this->mysqli->close();
}
}

$db = new dbMySQLi;
$db->connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Сам решил проблему. Добавил:

```
mysqli_set_charset($this->mysqli, "utf8");
```

Под:

```
public function connect(){
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте явно задать кодировку соединения при помощи отдельного запроса

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

MySQL по умолчанию ожидает, что клиент будет отправлять данные в кодировке latin1 (это связано с тем, что MySQL изначально шведская разработка). Даже если кодировка вашей базы данных UTF-8, даже если вы отправляете данные в UTF-8, она будет пытаться преобразовать latin1 в utf8.

Comment: Ясно же написано mysqli - i на конце. А ваше решение только для mysql.

Comment: Хотя коммент автора вопроса и чудовищно неграмотный, но, тем не менее, SET NAMES - это все равно неверный способ.

Comment: Мой ответ не относится к расширения PHP, если у вас в конфигурационном файле my.cnf не прописано, что соединение по умолчанию идет в utf-8, MySQL будет ожидать данные в latin1, и осуществлять преобразование.  Если у вас mysqli_set_charset() не настраивает кодировку соединения - нужно разбираться почему.

Comment: @Ипатьев, по хорошему нужно начинаться с корректной настройки сервера.

Comment: @Ипатьев почему неграмотный?

Comment: Настройка сервера здесь не при чем. И никакая настройка не сделает этот ответ верным.

Comment: @gm-111 ну, хотя бы потому что mysqli - это не база данных.

Comment: @Ипатьев я не писал, что mysqli - это база данных.